# How to set up a lightbox in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, lightbox

I am running Ruby on Rails 3 and I would like to use a [lightbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightbox_%28JavaScript%29) in my application, for example to show a login form and sign in users. I would like to use the *Prototype* framework.

**How is that possible?** *Do you have any advice or alert on this?*

P.S.: I would like to write as much as possible my proprietary code. Is that advisable?

Comment: This isn't really anything to do with Rails. Lightbox is just JavaScript, so you should be able to simply follow its documentation to set it up in your Rails views.

Comment: You say you want to use “a” lightbox in your app, and then link to the actual Lightbox project. So I'm assuming that you're using that framework to provide a lightbox facility in your Rails app.

That sounds fine to me, especially as you're already committed to Prototype as your Javascript library of choice. So I'm not sure what else you're asking. It certainly makes sense to use a tried and tested lightbox implementation rather than writing your own proprietary code, yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion the best lightbox are:

For prototype
- Lightview - http://www.nickstakenburg.com/projects/lightview/

For jQuery
- Facebox - http://chriswanstrath.com/facebox/

Answer (score 0):

not really specific to Rails but you'll want to use something like http://fancybox.net/ which makes use of JQuery. There are examples at the bottom for what you want to achieve which is a modal window. You'll need a view in your application that you'll load into the modal window - remember to not have an application layout on it otherwise you will have double layouts.

There are plenty of libraries out there that are tried and tested so unless there's a reason for not making use of them then I'd suggest using them rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Fancybox is a good one, and I use it with jQuery myself. But the OP has committed to prototype as his JS library, so I'd be more inclined to recommend Lightview.

Comment: yeah, the OP edited the post to mention prototype after I'd already replied mentioning jQuery :)

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.philburrows.com/articles/2008/05/05/porting-facebox-from-jquery-to-prototype/

facebox rewritten for prototype.

i use the jquery version on my site.  i changed the theme and removed a lot of stuff to simplify facebox but it's a good lightbox as is. quite good.